# How can I preserve the order of my ciphersuite list in OkHttp?

Tags: java, http, ssl, okhttp

I am unable to preserve the order of my ciphersuite list. I have set the order to be in my preferred way however, when the request is made and I check which order the ciphersuites are in, it is slightly different from my original. I am wondering if possibly okhttp is reordering them via a MAP structure or something else. If they are, I would like to learn where this is happening to be able to adjust it to preserve the order.

My connection spec used:

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_1, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2,TlsVersion.TLS_1_3)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
            )
            .build();
```

I want to also share that I am using conscrypt which enables these cipher suites. They are all used by okhttp but not in the correct order.

Comment: Bear in mind that SSL servers do not have to honor the order of the ciphersuites as presented by the client. The server may use its own preferences in selecting a ciphersuite.

Comment: Please describe how you've checked the order of cipher suites.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich order can be checked via https://ja3er.com/json

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in OkHttp https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6390

```
/**
 * Returns an array containing only elements found in this array and also in [other]. The returned
 * elements are in the same order as in this.
 */
fun Array<String>.intersect(
  other: Array<String>,
  comparator: Comparator<in String>
)
```

```
  private fun supportedSpec(sslSocket: SSLSocket, isFallback: Boolean): ConnectionSpec {
    var cipherSuitesIntersection = if (cipherSuitesAsString != null) {
      sslSocket.enabledCipherSuites.intersect(cipherSuitesAsString, CipherSuite.ORDER_BY_NAME)
    } else {
      sslSocket.enabledCipherSuites
    }
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246

```
The cipher suite list, passed from the client to the server in the
ClientHello message, contains the combinations of cryptographic
algorithms supported by the client in order of the client's
preference (favorite choice first). Each cipher suite defines a key
exchange algorithm, a bulk encryption algorithm (including secret key
length), a MAC algorithm, and a PRF. The server will select a cipher
suite or, if no acceptable choices are presented, return a handshake
failure alert and close the connection. If the list contains cipher
suites the server does not recognize, support, or wish to use, the
server MUST ignore those cipher suites, and process the remaining
ones as usual.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuri already mentioned that this is a [bug](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6390) within OkHttp. I am not quite sure how fast they will fix it but as an alternative you can still get it working with a delegate sslsocketfactory instead of using the `ConnectionSpec`

An example would setup would be:

**Your SSL properties**

```
SSLParameters sslParameters = new SSLParameters();
sslParameters.setProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.3", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"});
sslParameters.setCipherSuites(new String[]{
        "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
});
```

**Your custom SSLSocketFactory**

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public final class CompositeSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
    private final SSLParameters sslParameters;

    public CompositeSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, SSLParameters sslParameters) {
        this.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
        this.sslParameters = sslParameters;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return sslParameters.getCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return sslParameters.getCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket();
        return withSslParameters(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, InputStream inputStream, boolean autoClosable) throws IOException {
        Socket newSocket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, inputStream, autoClosable);
        return withSslParameters(newSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClosable) throws IOException {
        Socket newSocket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClosable);
        return withSslParameters(newSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
        return withSslParameters(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        return withSslParameters(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port);
        return withSslParameters(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
        return withSslParameters(socket);
    }

    private Socket withSslParameters(Socket socket) {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socket;
            sslSocket.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        }
        return socket;
    }

}
```

**Your OkHttp client configuration**

```
SSLContext sslContext = ...; //your already initialised SSLContext
X509TrustManager trustManager = ...; //your already initialised TrustManager

SSLSocketFactory baseSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocketFactory customSocketFactory = new CompositeSSLSocketFactory(baseSocketFactory, sslParameters);
            
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(customSocketFactory, trustManager)
    .build();
```

Yes it is verbose, however it will keep the order as you defined :) I would advise to wait for the [bug-fix](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6390), but if you want to fix it by your self for the time being than this would be an option.

Comment: This is incompatible with my programs and many others as my android app has Conscrypt added as its security provider. Conscrypt ignores the set sslSocketFactory and uses its own.

Comment: I have tried it with Conscrypt and on my side it works with the above setup. Could you explain how you use Conscrypt while setting up your OkHttp client? Maybe there is a way with your setup, but to help you I need some additional context... :)

Comment: @Hakan54, can you please share conscrypt implementation for your answer? Seems like setSSLParameters ignored on 2.5.2 and default cipher order used.